# Variable + Wildcard image removal

Tags: php, image

I want to create a piece of code that will remove images based on set parameters and a wildcard.

The number of images and naming will vary, though the first two parameters will remain as a constant.

// Example of images to be deleted / removed.

```
/images/1-50-variablename-A.jpg
/images/1-50-variablename-B.jpg
/images/1-50-variablename-C.jpg
/images/1-50-variablename-D.jpg
/images/1-50-variablename-E.jpg
```

Essentially I am after a loop to make this happen though I am not too sure on the best logic to make this happen.

```
$menuid = "1";
$imageid = "50"

$fileName = "images/".$menuid."-".$imageid."-*.jpg";
if (file_exists ($fileName)) {
unlink ($fileName);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php glob function (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php). Feed it with your pattern (it supports wildcards) and then iterate over the result and unlink each file.

Hope it helped

Comment: Never head of the Glob function, though it looks really cool! Thank you for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

Solution presented itself in Glob form.

```
$menuid ="9999";
$imageid="5";

array_map('unlink', glob("../images/".$menuid."-".$imageid."-*.jpg"));
```